# How to know the height of the div when its overflow is hidden

Tags: javascript, css, overflow

I have a div, which have overflow hidden. Now  want to display a arrow , up and down , up when we have overflow up and down arrow when we have overflow down.

And no arrows if there is no overflow in the div.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the `scrollHeight` property is greater than the element's `clientHeight`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

```js
if (el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Does that work with overflow: hidden or only overflow: scroll ?

Comment: It should work with both hidden and scroll

Comment: After more testing I see that this does work with overflow: hidden.  +1